# Overriding OpenSSL CipherString at a more granular level in Debian 10?

Tags: linux, debian, apache-httpd, openssl

In Debian 10, the upgraded OpenSSL package has more secure defaults (per https://wiki.debian.org/ContinuousIntegration/TriagingTips/openssl-1.1.1) which causes problems for some of my existing application configurations.

Changing **/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf** to use `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1` keeps my old configurations working but of course that's a system-wide change.

What I am wondering is if it is possible to keep the system default of `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2` and change this setting at a more granular level?

Specifically, I would like to change the setting on a per-site level in Apache if possible.

Comment: The setting is typically per application. For Apache, look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I believe the CipherString is different from the SSLCipherSuite (i.e. I can't see how to specify a SSLCipherSuite directive that is functionally identical to the openssl.cnf CipherString options)

Comment: `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` is just a default OpenSSL configuration, it is not necessarily used by applications. You are not clearly specifying which applications you use that depend on this file. The two are  the same thing: do `openssl ciphers -s -v 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=2'` and you will the specific ciphers that are included, which you can use then in your Apache configuration. Also search for SECLEVEL on https://access.redhat.com/articles/3652701 you will see you can use it directly in Apache configuration...

Answer (score 3):

- Override system default with user level environment:

  - An empty file will do: `touch ~/.openssl.cnf`
  - BASH define & export: `export OPENSSL_CONF=~/.openssl.cnf`
- Wrap application within a script: `export OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null`

Comment: I think that this answers the opposite to the original question.

Comment: Yes, original question is for per site granularity. I point out user level granularity may be useful if per site remains elusive.